# dplyr find length of specific row

Tags: r, list, dplyr, ranking

I am trying to find group length and the rank of each row in groups. I used dplyr for length and rank.

```
g.rank <- sample.df %>%
        group_by(retweet_id_str) %>%
        mutate(rank=row_number())
g.length <- sample.df %>%
        group_by(retweet_id_str) %>%
        summarise(length = n())
test <- merge(g.rank,g.length, by="retweet_id_str")
```

Result:

```
retweet_id_str     screen_name retweet_screen_name    tweet_created_at rank length
1    4.478178e+17     eyyupaluclu       GuneseYuruyen 2015-06-07 16:30:34    1      1
2    4.504073e+17     eyyupaluclu     melikemumcuoglu 2015-06-07 16:30:00    1      1
3    5.489578e+17       hadi_elis             dr_capa 2015-06-05 09:23:09    1      2
4    5.489578e+17      BozanHalit             dr_capa 2015-06-05 09:33:56    2      2
5    5.552862e+17    cevatdemiral           haber3com 2015-06-21 00:54:09    1      3
6    5.552862e+17    cevatdemiral           haber3com 2015-06-21 23:59:04    2      3
7    5.552862e+17    cevatdemiral           haber3com 2015-06-22 21:54:55    3      3
```

In my data set, users in the screen_name can be repeated so if one user is repeated in different groups, I need to calculate this;

```
user= [group1(lenght/rank) + group2(lenght/rank)]/ total group number
* Each unique "retweet_id_str" is a one group.
```

Example;

```
- One user-two different group: 
eyyupaluclu =[group1(1/1)+group2(1/1)]/2 = 1
```

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

PS: If my question is not clear, please let me know. I am ready to make it clear.

Data sample:

```
sample.df <-structure(list(screen_name = c("eyyupaluclu", "eyyupaluclu", 
                                           "hadi_elis", "BozanHalit", "cevatdemiral", "cevatdemiral", "cevatdemiral", 
                                           "hadi_elis", "xtutunusx", "hadi_elis", "umutsu15", "OkanBoyner", 
                                           "BayarTun", "Ayhan34Isikli", "JindaAxin", "JindaAxin", "JindaAxin", 
                                           "JindaAxin", "OtoTeski", "b8f767a3022b4ee", "OtoTeski", "b8f767a3022b4ee", 
                                           "OtoTeski", "b8f767a3022b4ee", "OtoTeski", "OtoTeski", "OtoTeski", 
                                           "ankakusu1963", "ankakusu1963", "ankakusu1963", "cengizbayel", 
                                           "tarlaci5334", "sehven55", "cengizbayel", "ErdogduKezban", "Ayhan34Isikli", 
                                           "Ayhan34Isikli", "melekaydinkocak", "IrtegunUgur", "IrtegunUgur", 
                                           "melekaydinkocak", "AKinonuatasehir", "RTESLM", "vardar_filiz", 
                                           "IrtegunUgur", "AksemsettinMh", "glcihansnmezer", "esesli_murat", 
                                           "huseyinvarlik26", "ahmetkaraman001"), 
                           retweet_screen_name = c("GuneseYuruyen","melikemumcuoglu", "dr_capa", "dr_capa", "haber3com", "haber3com",
                                                   "haber3com", "GeorgetownDG", "19811923_", "meforum", "BasarKurtan", 
                                                   "SBELBULUT", "tuncaybayar52", "Akkadinistanbul", "medyayakurdi",
                                                   "medyayakurdi", "medyayakurdi", "medyayakurdi", "twit_komedyeni", 
                                                   "twit_komedyeni", "twit_komedyeni", "twit_komedyeni", "twit_komedyeni",
                                                   "twit_komedyeni", "twit_komedyeni", "twit_komedyeni", "twit_komedyeni", 
                                                   "mr_dogan", "mr_dogan", "mr_dogan", "memetsimsek", "DevletBaskanRTE", 
                                                   "ErkanGuven", "memetsimsek", "Akkadinistanbul", "Akkadinistanbul", 
                                                   "Akkadinistanbul", "_aliuzun", "akgencistanbul", "akgenc_kadikoy", 
                                                   "Hocazade_", "atasehirakparti", "oguz__kaya", "oguz__kaya", "AkTanitimMedya", 
                                                   "AkTanitimMedya", "AkTanitimMedya", "GencAkparti26", "GencAkparti26", 
                                                   "GencAkparti26"),
                           tweet_created_at = c("2015-06-07 16:30:34", "2015-06-07 16:30:00", "2015-06-05 09:23:09", "2015-06-05 09:33:56", 
                                                "2015-06-21 00:54:09", "2015-06-21 23:59:04", "2015-06-22 21:54:55", 
                                                "2015-05-18 23:05:59", "2015-06-03 06:17:24", "2015-05-31 13:48:10", 
                                                "2015-05-28 12:18:45", "2015-05-28 17:01:07", "2015-06-03 16:48:57", 
                                                "2015-05-09 07:19:29", "2015-05-09 07:36:41", "2015-05-09 07:36:46", 
                                                "2015-05-09 07:36:50", "2015-05-09 07:36:52", "2015-05-14 09:43:00", 
                                                "2015-06-13 05:19:03", "2015-05-14 09:42:39", "2015-06-13 05:18:48", 
                                                "2015-05-14 09:42:42", "2015-06-13 05:18:54", "2015-05-14 09:42:50", 
                                                "2015-05-14 09:42:47", "2015-05-14 09:42:53", "2015-05-17 23:06:16", 
                                                "2015-05-17 23:05:08", "2015-05-17 23:04:56", "2015-05-09 16:32:06", 
                                                "2015-05-09 17:35:28", "2015-05-08 03:14:29", "2015-05-09 16:31:50", 
                                                "2015-05-08 00:24:57", "2015-05-09 07:17:42", "2015-05-09 07:17:38", 
                                                "2015-05-16 19:29:58", "2015-05-08 07:15:22", "2015-05-08 07:15:18", 
                                                "2015-05-16 19:29:25", "2015-05-08 03:21:30", "2015-05-14 06:50:50", 
                                                "2015-05-14 06:54:07", "2015-05-08 07:14:13", "2015-05-09 17:41:35", 
                                                "2015-05-09 17:58:56", "2015-05-08 04:59:54", "2015-05-09 02:34:12", 
                                                "2015-05-10 07:38:01"),
                           retweet_id_str = c(447817783829860352, 450407343604629504, 548957776895303680, 548957776895303680, 555286212916035584, 
                                              555286212916035584, 555286212916035584, 561187125438451712, 573054097726840832, 
                                              584809040380760064, 587723931919986688, 588382883733176320, 592766311387832320, 
                                              593336106013347840, 593453258716409856, 593453420641652736, 593453598975119360, 
                                              593453994799935488, 594907386885836800, 594907386885836800, 594907487125577728, 
                                              594907487125577728, 594907617866166272, 594907617866166272, 594907731506667520, 
                                              594907807331254272, 594907964017881088, 594957981340532736, 594961968521420800, 
                                              594964791598387200, 595130224523743232, 595160203596865536, 595176402967777280, 
                                              595183002243719168, 595211840055078912, 595211840055078912, 595211943088009216, 
                                              595212869400186880, 595212974190678016, 595213691026591744, 595213757216858112, 
                                              595213790863568896, 595214683541544960, 595214683541544960, 595214727321677824, 
                                              595214727321677824, 595214727321677824, 595214737861804032, 595214737861804032, 
                                              595214737861804032)), 
                      .Names = c("screen_name", "retweet_screen_name", 
                                 "tweet_created_at", "retweet_id_str"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), 
                      row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

Comment: I think your retweet id strings should be stored as strings. If stored as floating point numbers, they'll run into the usual rounding problems.

Comment: It works fine until now but I'll consider it. Thanks

Comment: @Frank they are not floats but scientific representations of integers. There should not be any rounding problems.

Comment: @Prolix there will certainly be rounding problems with integers on the order of `10^17` unless you are using `gmp` or some other big integer package. These are all above your built-in `.Machine$integer.max`.

Comment: E.g., `1e17 == 1e17 + 1` gives `# [1] TRUE`

Comment: @ebanoz, for "length of group" and `length_of_group = n()` to your `mutate`. For the "repeat of screen_name in different groups" maybe you could show desired output? I'm confused by what you have. Now that you've solved half your question, maybe you could edit it so it only shows what you *don't* know how to do?

Comment: @Gregor Ok my bad I thought R was working with long ints (64bits -> 9.10^18). I learned something :)

Comment: Hi @Gregor, I'll put some output for it.

Comment: Hey @Gregor, I put a sample data for different groups problem. I hope that it can be able to give some idea. Thanks,

Comment: How about editing down the question? It's far too long for my attention span. You share your data twice, show a solution to a question that's already solved (seems irrelevant), and I'm still not sure what your desired result is (maybe it's in there, but I don't have the patience to read the whole thing when most of it seems unnecessary).

Comment: Hi @Gregor, I edited my question and I hope that it is cleaner than before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough. Looks like you want the mean value of `length/rank` for each `screen_name`:

```
test %>% mutate(l_over_r = length / rank) %>%
    group_by(screen_name) %>%
    summarize(user = mean(l_over_r))
```

If a user is in one group only, the mean will of course be the same value. If the user is in 2 groups then `group1(l_over_r) + group2(l_over_r) / 2` is the average (mean), and this generalizes up nicely. If you really only want this calculated for users in *exactly* two groups then you can pre-filter:

```
test %>% mutate(l_over_r = length / rank) %>%
    group_by(screen_name) %>%
    filter(n() == 2) %>%
    summarize(user = mean(l_over_r))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#       screen_name  user
#             (chr) (dbl)
# 1     cengizbayel     1
# 2     eyyupaluclu     1
# 3 melekaydinkocak     1
```

As a side note, since you're using `dplyr` you should get in the habit of using `left_join` instead of `merge`, for example in `test <- lef_join(g.rank, g.length, by="retweet_id_str")`/

Comment: Thanks @Gregor, I am really appreciate your solution and advice for the question.